# How heroku postgres works with 0 bytes of RAM

Tags: postgresql, heroku

On heroku postgres plan page https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql, it is mentioned that for hobby plans there is 0 bytes of RAM. Does it mean that Postgres  is working without RAM?

Comment: That'd be impossible. At a guess, it probably means "nothing guaranteed, you get whatever RAM we can spare"

Answer (score 2):

The 0 bytes RAM refers to the amount of [in-memory cache](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-query.html) allocated to your datastore. [Heroku says...](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#hobby-tier)

> The lack of an in-memory cache limits performance, because the data can’t be accessed on low-latency storage.

Comment: I came here after reading the documentation above, because I'm trying to figure out whether this has any implications for a single query. Joins and subqueries are sometimes performed by creating a temporary table with a subset or combination of other tables. Does this count as "cache"? Are the lower tiers forced to use disk for temp tables or perhaps to avoid this optimization?

Comment: My interpretation of the docs is that if you're on the Hobby plan, there _is no RAM-based cache_. As a result all queries--simple _and_ complex--will be pulling from disk.